# Step Property for a circular slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could anyone please help me in creating a stepper function that would take a parameter 'n' and would increment my slider according to n's value. Circular slider I'm using is this :

https://github.com/fseehawer/react-circular-slider

This is how the knob is being set based on different angles, but what if I want to set the knob at angles separated with 20 degree angle.

```
const setKnobPosition = useCallback(
    (radians) => {
      const radius = state.radius - trackSize / 2;
      const offsetRadians = radians + knobOffset[knobPosition];
      const degrees = (offsetRadians > 0 ? offsetRadians : 2 * Math.PI + offsetRadians)
          * (spreadDegrees / (2 * Math.PI));

      const pointsInCircle = (state.angles.length - 1) / spreadDegrees;
      const currentPoint = Math.round(degrees * pointsInCircle);
      if (state.angles[currentPoint] !== state.currentPoint) {
        onChange(state.angles[currentPoint]);
      }

      dispatch({
        type: 'setKnobPosition',
        payload: {
          displayedCompassAngle: state.angles[currentPoint],
          knob: {
            x: radius * Math.cos(radians) + radius,
            y: radius * Math.sin(radians) + radius,
          },
        },
      });
    },
    [
      state.radius,
      state.angles,
      state.displayedCompassAngle,
      knobPosition,
      trackSize,
      direction,
      onChange,
    ],
  );
```

These are initial state and different props I am using.

```
const CircularSlider = (props) => {
  const {
    width = 280,
    direction = 1,
    knobPosition = 'top',
    hideLabelValue = false,
    knobDraggable = true,
    trackSize = 8,
    angles = [],
    compassAngle = 0,
    onChange = () => {},
  } = props;

  const initialState = {
    mounted: false,
    isDragging: false,
    width,
    radius: width / 2,
    knobPosition,
    displayedCompassAngle: 0,
    angles,
    radians: 0,
    offset: 0,
    knob: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
    },
  };
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you share the code that you currently tried to use with the library?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular ***[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62786741/edit)*** your question description to add details – don't add answers to provide those details like below.